# Sending data using Hashtable on Photon Cloud

Tags: c++, cloud, marmalade, photon

I am trying to send data using Hashtable on photon cloud, I do receive the data with correct eventCode, but the key-value pair returns some random numbers. My code is like this while sending data:-

```
void NetworkLogic::sendEvent(void)
{
    ExitGames::Common::Hashtable* table =new ExitGames::Common::Hashtable;
        table->put<int,int>(4,21);
        const ExitGames::Common::Hashtable temp = (const ExitGames::Common::Hashtable)*table;//= new ExitGames::Common::Hashtable;
        mLoadBalancingClient.opRaiseEvent(false, temp, 100);
}
```

While receiving data, the code is like this:-

```
void NetworkLogic::customEventAction(int playerNr, nByte eventCode, const ExitGames::Common::Hashtable& eventContent)
{
    // you do not receive your own events, unless you specify yourself as one of the receivers explicitly, so you must start 2 clients, to receive the events, which you have sent, as sendEvent() uses the default receivers of opRaiseEvent() (all players in same room like the sender, except the sender itself)
    PhotonPeer_sendDebugOutput(&mLoadBalancingClient, DEBUG_LEVEL_ALL, L"");
    cout<<((int)(eventContent.getValue(4)));
}
```

What I get printed on console is some random values or int, while it should be 21. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
In `customEventAction()` when I used the following statement:

```
cout<<eventContent.getValue(4)->getType()<<endl;
cout<<"Event code = "<<eventCode<<endl;
```

I got the following output:

```
i
Event code = d
```

I searched and found that `'i'` is the value of `EG_INTEGER` which means the value I am sending is getting received properly. I am just not been able to convert it back to `int`. And why the event code is coming as `'d'`?

Comment: Please ignore the last line. I forgot to cast the eventcode to int, so it was printing char :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eventContent.getValue(4)
```

returns an Object.
You can't simply cast that Object to int, but have to access the int value inside it:

```
if(eventContent.getValue(4))
            myInt = ExitGames::Common::ValueObject<int>(eventContent.getValue(4)).getDataCopy();
cout << myInt;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. This code worked, although I need to do some minor edits, which I did in your answer too. Thanks again, now My Multiplayer thing will be complete.